# Display total price and total items in minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have installed magento 2.0.7 and overide the template minicart.phtml to my custom theme. I want to show total price and total items in the header minicart like the below image[image]

Comment: Hi, have you found solution to above ? as I am Looking for the same.

Comment: Yes arun.I will post my answer

Comment: thank you, I have figured it out, but if you can, I want `$00 - 0 item` to be printed by default if 0 product is in the cart. in Magento 2.1.0. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Working code for me. Magento 2.2.4

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
           data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number">
            <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: '0' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>

        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>

        <span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') != 1 -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                <span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>

        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use AJAX along with the API unless there is already a function for this in the Magento/Checkout/Model... Find the minicart knockout js template for an example already in your code.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_overview.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Please make a copy of minicart.phtml file in your theme (\app\design\frontend\yourpackage\yourtheme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml) and add the below code in it

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');?>
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count < 0 }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="ex-top-cart-subtotal">
            <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
                <!-- ko if: cart().possible_onepage_checkout -->
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko --></span>

            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko ifnot: cart().summary_count -->
            &pound; <!-- ko i18n: ' 0.00 - 0 item ' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
                <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count == 1 -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count > 1 -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <?php //echo "&pound; ".number_format($helper->getQuote()->getSubtotal(), 2, '.', '');?>
            </span>

        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain what you changed....

Answer (score -1):

Go to this directory `\app\design\frontend\yourpackage\yourtheme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml`

and overwrite with below code in minicart.phtml file.

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span> 
    <span class="counter qty empty" data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 }, css: { empty: !cart().summary_count }, blockLoader: isLoading">
        <span class="counter-number"> 

            <!-- ko if: !cart().summary_count -->
                <!-- ko i18n: '0 item' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko --> 
            <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count >= 1 -->
                <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --> 
                <!-- ko i18n: ' items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->  
        </span>  
        <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: cart().subtotal_excl_tax"> </span> 
        <span class="price-custom-minicart">
        <!-- ko if: !cart().subtotal_excl_tax -->
            <!-- ko i18n: '€ 0.00' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        <span class="counter-label">
        <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
            <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```